# Image doesn't properly cover the button

Tags: java, image, button, javafx, fxml

I am unable to properly adjust the size of the image so that both the image and the button fit one another.

**Here is the important part of the code:**

```
<Button prefHeight="80" prefWidth="80" id="LifeLine">
   <shape>
       <javafx.scene.shape.Circle radius="1"/>
    </shape>
</Button>
```

**The CSS File**

```
#LifeLine
{
-fx-background-image: url("/millionairetriviagame/ImageFiles/AudienceButton.png");
-fx-smooth: true;
-fx-background-repeat: stretch; 
-fx-background-size: 80 80;
-fx-background-position: center center;
-fx-background-insets: 0, 0, 0, 0;
}
```

**Here is a screenshot. The button on the top far left is the problem.**

[image]

**Edit**

Now I got the button to like this with the code that I posted.

[image]

Comment: Set css display block to the button, or inline-block

Comment: @GiacomoPaita Well in my CSS file I'm able to do -fx-display-caret: but there isn't something like -fx-display: inline-block; that I can use.

Comment: What type of CSS rule is -fx?

Comment: @GiacomoPaita it's CSS integrated with javafx I should say.

Comment: I see that you've edited your question: did you eventually solve your issue?

Comment: @GiacomoPaita Nope not yet

Comment: Mmmm, if you could manage to make a fiddle or jsbin, i could make a glimpse to the code. I'm not an expert of java-stuff-css, only CSS. Sorry for my english...

Comment: @GiacomoPaita I got a solution

Comment: @Giacomo, here is the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) which defines many of the `-fx-` properties used in JavaFX CSS.  Although JavaFX uses the same CSS language as HTML based CSS, the CSS properties used with JavaFX and the element types to which they apply are completely different, so JavaFX CSS rules can only be demonstrated in JavaFX applications, not in fiddles or jsbin.

Comment: Understand. But, is there something like a staging link to test and debug the CSS output code?

Answer (score 0):

Change background repeat to no-repeat or delete that property

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite the answer because there is still a small gap between the button and the image, but it is the best solution I can offer at the moment. The image with this code is now centered to the button and it is not repeating. Now I need to figure out why both the image circle and the button circle are not the same size even though they have the same height and width.

```
<Button prefHeight="80" prefWidth="80" >
   <shape>
         <javafx.scene.shape.Circle radius="1" /> 
   </shape>
   <graphic>
       <ImageView fitHeight="80" fitWidth="80" smooth="true" >
           <image>
                 <Image url="@ImageFiles/AudienceButton.png"/>
           </image>    
      </ImageView>
  </graphic>
</Button>
```

**Better Solution**

```
     <Button prefHeight="70" prefWidth="70"  >
                    <shape>
                        <javafx.scene.shape.Circle radius="1" /> 
                    </shape>
                    <graphic>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="70" fitWidth="70" scaleX="1.2" scaleY="1.2"  smooth="true" >
                            <image>
                                <Image url="@ImageFiles/AudienceButton.png"/>
                            </image>    
                        </ImageView>
                    </graphic>
                </Button>
```

All I had to do was to scale the image to the size of the button from the x and y direction.